# How to terminate an unarchive process safely?

Tags: macos, big-sur

I was trying to unzip a downloaded Xcode xip file. The unarchiving has been running for hours so I tried to cancel it. Now it is stuck in cancelling.

I think it took such a long time was because I was running low of disk space. Is there any safe way to kill this process and reclaim any working space?

[image]

Comment: Running close to full on storage media is a recipe for problems. I run below 50% used…

Comment: I had the same issue some time ago, the only thing that helped was a restart (I could kill Archive Utility from Apple menu > Force Quit, but a restart was necessary to reclaim the disk space).